# Event Handling mouse events with React refs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, slider

Hi I am trying to convert the below HTML and vanilla JS for Sliders with multiple thumbs code to React class component but facing some issue while attaching event handlers to refs.
Any suggestions to replicate the same behavior?

Slider.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script defer src="Slider.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="bar" id="bar">
          <div class="slider" id="slider-1"></div>
          <div class="slider" id="slider-2"></div>
          <div class="slider" id="slider-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="values">
        <div class="value" id="value-1">3</div>
        <div class="value" id="value-2">4</div>
        <div class="value" id="value-3">5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Slider.js

```
const slider1 = document.getElementById('slider-1');
const value1 = document.getElementById('value-1');

const slider2 = document.getElementById('slider-2');
const value2 = document.getElementById('value-2');

const slider3 = document.getElementById('slider-3');
const value3 = document.getElementById('value-3');

const bar = document.getElementById('bar');
// let lastOffset = 0;
let lastOffset1 = 0;
let posCurrentX1 = 0;
let lastOffset2 = 0;
let posCurrentX2 = 0;
let lastOffset3 = 0;
let posCurrentX3 = 0;
const barLength = getComputedStyle(bar).width;
const sliderWidth = getComputedStyle(slider1).width;
let travelLength = Math.round(barLength.substring(0, barLength.length - 2)); // -
//   sliderWidth.substring(0, sliderWidth.length - 2) / 2;
const range = 100;

slider1.onmousedown = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const posInitialX = event.clientX;

  document.onmouseup = (event) => {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
    lastOffset1 = posCurrentX1;
  };

  document.onmousemove = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    posCurrentX1 = lastOffset1 + event.clientX - posInitialX;

    // console.log(window.innerWidth);
    // console.log(document.body.style.width);

    if (posCurrentX1 <= travelLength && posCurrentX1 >= 0) {
      //   console.log('posCurrentX: ', posCurrentX, 'barLength: ', travelLength);
      slider1.style.left = `${posCurrentX1}px`;
      value1.innerHTML = Math.round((range / travelLength) * posCurrentX1);
    }
  };
};

slider2.onmousedown = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const posInitialX = event.clientX;

  document.onmouseup = (event) => {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
    lastOffset2 = posCurrentX2;
  };

  document.onmousemove = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    posCurrentX2 = lastOffset2 + event.clientX - posInitialX;

    // console.log(window.innerWidth);
    // console.log(document.body.style.width);

    if (posCurrentX2 <= travelLength && posCurrentX2 >= 0) {
      // console.log('posCurrentX: ', posCurrentX, 'barLength: ', travelLength);
      slider2.style.left = `${posCurrentX2}px`;
      value2.innerHTML = Math.round((range / travelLength) * posCurrentX2);
    }
  };
};

slider3.onmousedown = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const posInitialX = event.clientX;

  document.onmouseup = (event) => {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
    lastOffset3 = posCurrentX3;
  };

  document.onmousemove = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    posCurrentX3 = lastOffset3 + event.clientX - posInitialX;

    // console.log(window.innerWidth);
    // console.log(document.body.style.width);

    if (posCurrentX3 <= travelLength && posCurrentX3 >= 0) {
      // console.log('posCurrentX: ', posCurrentX3, 'barLength: ', travelLength);
      slider3.style.left = `${posCurrentX3}px`;
      value3.innerHTML = Math.round((range / travelLength) * posCurrentX3);
    }
  };
};
```

Slider.js (React version)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Slider.css";

let lastOffset1 = 0;
let posCurrentX1 = 0;
let lastOffset2 = 0;
let posCurrentX2 = 0;
let lastOffset3 = 0;
let posCurrentX3 = 0;
const barLength = this.refs.bar.current.width;
const sliderWidth = this.refs.slider1.current.width;
let travelLength = Math.round(barLength.substring(0, barLength.length - 2)); // -
//   sliderWidth.substring(0, sliderWidth.length - 2) / 2;
const range = 100;

class CombinedSlider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.slider1 = React.createRef();
    this.slider2 = React.createRef();
    this.slider3 = React.createRef();
    this.value1 = React.createRef();
    this.value2 = React.createRef();
    this.value3 = React.createRef();
    this.bar = React.createRef();
  }; 

    onmousedown1 = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    const posInitialX = event.clientX;
  
    this.slider1.current.onMouseUp = (event) => {
        this.slider1.current.onmousemove = null;
        this.slider1.current.onmouseup = null;
      lastOffset1 = posCurrentX1;
    };
  
    this.slider1.current.onMouseMove= (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
  
      posCurrentX1 = lastOffset1 + event.clientX - posInitialX;
  
      // console.log(window.innerWidth);
      // console.log(document.body.style.width);
  
      if (posCurrentX1 <= travelLength && posCurrentX1 >= 0) {
        //   console.log('posCurrentX: ', posCurrentX, 'barLength: ', travelLength);
        this.slider1.current.style.left = `${posCurrentX1}px`;
        this.value1.current.innerHTML = Math.round((range / travelLength) * posCurrentX1);
      }
    };
  };
  onmousedown2 = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    const posInitialX = event.clientX;
  
    this.slider2.current.onMouseUp = (event) => {
        this.slider2.current.onMouseMove = null;
        this.slider2.current.onMouseUp = null;
      lastOffset2 = posCurrentX2;
    };
  
    this.slider2.current.onMouseMove = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
  
      posCurrentX2 = lastOffset2 + event.clientX - posInitialX;
  
      // console.log(window.innerWidth);
      // console.log(document.body.style.width);
  
      if (posCurrentX2 <= travelLength && posCurrentX2 >= 0) {
        // console.log('posCurrentX: ', posCurrentX, 'barLength: ', travelLength);
        this.slider2.current.style.left = `${posCurrentX2}px`;
        this.value2.current.innerHTML = Math.round((range / travelLength) * posCurrentX2);
      }
    };
  };
onmousedown3 = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    const posInitialX = event.clientX;
  
    this.slider3.current.onMouseUp = (event) => {
        this.slider3.current.onMouseMove = null;
        this.slider3.current.onMouseUp = null;
      lastOffset3 = posCurrentX3;
    };
  
    this.slider3.current.onMouseMove = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
  
      posCurrentX3 = lastOffset3 + event.clientX - posInitialX;
  
      // console.log(window.innerWidth);
      // console.log(document.body.style.width);
  
      if (posCurrentX3 <= travelLength && posCurrentX3 >= 0) {
        // console.log('posCurrentX: ', posCurrentX3, 'barLength: ', travelLength);
        this.slider3.current.style.left = `${posCurrentX3}px`;
        this.value3.current.innerHTML = Math.round((range / travelLength) * posCurrentX3);
      }
    };
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="box">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="bar" id="bar">
              <div className="slider" id="slider-1" ref={slider1 => this.slider1 = slider1 } onMouseDown={this.onmousedown1} />
              <div className="slider" id="slider-2" ref={slider2 => this.slider2 = slider2} onMouseDown={this.onmousedown2}/>
              <div className="slider" id="slider-3" ref={slider3 => this.slider3 = slider3} onMouseDown={this.onmousedown3}/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="values">
            <div className="value" id="value-1" ref={value1 => this.value1=value1}>
              3
            </div>
            <div className="value" id="value-2" ref={value2 => this.value2=value2}>
              4
            </div>
            <div className="value" id="value-3" ref={value3 => this.value3 = value3}>
              5
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CombinedSlider;
```

For example
slider1.onmousedown = (event) =>
function, How should I implement the same behavior using refs. I am getting ref object is not extensible and undefined errors while trying to attach onMouseDown() event listeners to it. Somehow I am stuck trying to replicate the same behavior.

Also is there any elegant way of doing this apart from using refs?

Comment: can you turn it into a functional component and then use the hook useEffect?
Something like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60513173/how-to-add-an-event-listener-to-useref-in-useeffect

Comment: you have to put all lets and const values inside class component... how do you want to use this.refs outside of it? it is impossible